# Python - show path, simple socket problem

Tags: python, sockets

I recently ventured into python in 3.7
I want to make a server / client whose client will show the path I put in input (macOS):

Server

```
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 1337              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        info = conn.recv(1024)
        print(info)
        raw_input("Push to exit")
        s.close()
```

Client :

```
import socket
import os

HOST = ''    # The remote host
PORT = 1337              # The same port as used by the server
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    print('Connected')
    info = os.listdir("/Users/jhon")
    s.send(str(info))
    s.close()
```

1. Server start and it's listening...
2. python client.py Connected Traceback (most recent call last):   File
   "client.py", line 10, in 
       s.send(str(info)) **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'** (not understand this), and after client start, in server show:
3. Connected by ('127.0.0.1', 52155) b'' Traceback (most recent call
   last):   File "server.py", line 13, in 
       raw_input("press for exit") NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined (venv) MBP-di-Jhon:untitled1 jhon$

Answer (score 1):

You ventured into 3.7 from some 2.x version without modifying the 2.x code.  Read something about the [differences](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/important-differences-between-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-with-examples/) before continuing.  To help you get started:

Replace `raw_input` with `input`.  (One could replace 2.x `input()` with `eval(input())`, but one should nearly always use a more specific evaluator, such as `int(input())`.)

In 3.x, strings are unicode, whereas sockets still require bytes.  Change `send` and `recv` to

```
s.send(str(info).encode())
info = conn.recv(1024).decode()
```

Comment: Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to change the **client** code to:

```
HOST = ''    # The remote host
PORT = 1337              # The same port as used by the server
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    print('Connected')
    info  = "\n".join(os.listdir("/Users/jhon"))
    s.send(info.encode())
    s.send(info)
    s.close()
```

---

`os.listdir("/Users/jhon")` returns a `list`, we use `join` and `encode` to make it `byte` object, which is needed for `s.send()`